# How do you jump through animation keyframes in a loop?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet, timeline

How do you jump through animation keyframes in a loop? Currently when using the "jump to keyframe" hotkey the playhead stops on the last keyframe rather than going back to the start.

I can press "Spacebar" to loop an animation but I'd like to loop through keyframes with a hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

I'd also like an answer for the same problem.

My workaround is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> arrow to go to the start/end.

Also setting the automatic play range <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> helps. When I press the above hotkeys, it goes to first/last keyframe.